# ExtractImagePatches is not supported

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx, onnx-coreml, tf2onnx

I'm trying to convert TensorFlow model to onnx format by tf2onnx 1.12.1. But I get errors for converting my first layers (they are BatchNormalization).

Code to create the layer:

```
# Layer 1
x, _ = Involution(channel=3, group_number=1, kernel_size=3, stride=1, reduction_ratio=2, name="inv_rgb")(input_image, dep_image)

x = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(x)

x = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(x)

x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)



y, _ = Involution_depth(channel=3, group_number=1, kernel_size=3, stride=2, reduction_ratio=1, name="inv_dep")(dep_image)
#y = Conv2D(32, (3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='same', name='dconv_1', use_bias=False)(dep_image)

y = BatchNormalization(name='dnorm_1')(y)

y = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)(y)

y = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(y)
```

code to convert tf model to onnx:

```
import onnx
import tf2onnx
# Output the model to ONNX format.
model.load_weights('./weightModel.h5')
tf.saved_model.save(model, "tmp_model")

!python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model tmp_model --output "weightFinal12.onnx"
```

The error:

> ERROR - Tensorflow op [StatefulPartitionedCall/functional_1/inv_rgb/ExtractImagePatches: ExtractImagePatches] is not supported

Answer (score 0):

The involution layer, that you used, use ExtractImagePatches operator, that is not supported by ONNX. Stay tuned with this issue: https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/4560